# IntelliJ won't resolve Java dependency on Scala File

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I normally start an intelliJ Scala project, but weirdly I found it unable to parse Java  dependency:

```
import java.io.File
```

If I just put this line up, the `java` word will be highlighted in red indicating it's missing.

Some Java compatible String method `trim`can't be resolved as well.

What's happening and what should I do?

Btw, I searched online quite extensively, but many solutions are for older versions or can't really solve my problem.

---

Yup, it won't even parse:

```
  val dictionary = Map(
    """will""" -> 1,
    """going to""" -> 2
  )
```

the `->` in the middle turns red as `can't resolve symbol`.

The same as: `val regex = word.r`. My IntelliJ can't resolve `.r`. Is this normal?

Comment: Check if your project has JDK properly set up. Look into `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project` -> `Project SDK`

Comment: That's it! @ghik I checked everything except Project SDK. IntelliJ linked my project SDK to some invalid JDK...thank you!!